# What's the difference between MySQL's AUTO_INCREMENT and PEAR DB's nextID?

Tags: mysql, pear

Is there an advantage of one over the other? Thanks.

Comment: PEAR is a database abstraction layer. It provides a common interface to a number of different possible RDBMS systems including but not limited to MySQL. Some of those RDBMS systems have entities called sequences. nextID is a method to request the next value from one of those sequences. MySQL is not one of those RDBMS's. There's no reasonable way to directly answer your question; you're comparing apples to oranges -- or should I say -- PEARs to oranges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: PEAR DB should not be used anymore. Use MDB2 instead.

Seconds: nextId works on all DBMS, not only MySQL.

Comment: I know you answered this a while back but I just wnat to say thank you for answering!